# python - lxml - How to tag words in texts gracefully?

Tags: python, xml, lxml

I need to tag certain words with lxml. Take this as an example,

```
<span>Please BOLD me, <br /> BOLD me too</span>
```

I need to find out all certain words, 'BOLD' here , and add tags to them. The result should be:

```
<span>Please <b>BOLD</b> me, <br /> <b>BOLD</b> me too</span>
```

It must use **lxml**, it is not only a regular expression problem. It needs some program calculation before tagging. More like this:

```
s = '<span>Please BOLD me, <br /> BOLD me too</span>'
from lxml import etree
et = etree.fromstring(s)
for e in et.iter():
    if 'BOLD' in e.text:
        **tag it**
    if 'BOLD' in e.tail:
        **tag it**
```

I guess I need to create an element `bold = etree.Element('b'); bold.text = 'BOLD'`

The problem is I don't know how to insert the above element `bold` gracefully.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to manually create a `<b>` element and `.insert()` it in place. Put the remaining text in the `tail` of the created element:

```
import lxml.html
from lxml.html import builder as E

text = '''
<html>
 <body>
   <span>Please BOLD me</span>
 </body>
</html>
'''

doc = lxml.html.fromstring(text)
for span in doc.xpath('//span'):
    # search for the word "BOLD" in the span text:
    pre, sep, pos = span.text.partition('BOLD')
    if sep:
        span.text = pre
        bold = E.B(sep) # create element
        bold.tail = pos
        span.insert(0, bold)


print(lxml.html.tostring(doc, pretty_print=True))
```

The results:

```
<html>
 <body>
   <span>Please <b>BOLD</b> me</span>
 </body>
</html>
```

If you find it in a tail, then you have to insert the new element in the parent, just after the element you found:

```
parent = element.getparent()
parent.insert(parent.index(element) + 1, bold)
```